# How to send HTML-formatted email?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I could be able to let the web application sends automatic emails using Windows Task Scheduler. Now I want to send HTML-Formatted email using the following method that I wrote for sending emails.

My code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("mail address");
        MailMessage msg = null;

        try
        {
            msg = new MailMessage("xxxx@gmail.com",
                "yyyy@gmail.com", "Message from PSSP System",
                "This email sent by the PSSP system");

             sc.Send(msg);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (msg != null)
            {
                msg.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

How to do that? I just want to put some bold text with one link and maybe one image in the email.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

Setting `isBodyHtml` to `true` allows you to use HTML tags in the message body:

```
msg = new MailMessage("xxxx@gmail.com",
                "yyyy@gmail.com", "Message from PSSP System",
                "This email sent by the PSSP system<br />" +
                "<b>this is bold text!</b>");

msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: Can we use a custom font??

Comment: You can't customise fonts easily as custom fonts need to be supported by the mail client. A lot of mail clients still use very basic pre IE6 type of HTML so they will default to another font.

Comment: So I don't need to use <HTML><BODY> tags?

Comment: So if I want to add html in email subject, is that possible? In Subject I need to show  in bold format like **[Action Neede]** on this request.

Answer (score 94):

Best way to send html formatted Email

This code will be in "**Customer.htm**"

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Dealer's Company Name
        </td>
        <td>
            :
        </td>
        <td>
            #DealerCompanyName#
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Read HTML file Using System.IO.File.ReadAllText. get all HTML code in string variable.

```
string Body = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("EmailTemplates/Customer.htm"));
```

Replace Particular string to your custom value.

```
Body = Body.Replace("#DealerCompanyName#", _lstGetDealerRoleAndContactInfoByCompanyIDResult[0].CompanyName);
```

call SendEmail(string Body) Function and do procedure to send email.

```
 public static void SendEmail(string Body)
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(Session["Email"].Tostring());
            message.To.Add(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["RequesEmail"].ToString());
            message.Subject = "Request from " + SessionFactory.CurrentCompany.CompanyName + " to add a new supplier";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = Body;

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            smtpClient.Host = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SMTP"].ToString();
            smtpClient.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PORT"].ToString());
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["USERNAME"].ToString(), ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PASSWORD"].ToString());
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
```

Comment: Maybe use **MailDefinition** or **RazorEngine** ***http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512845/how-to-send-email-wth-email-template-c-sharp***

Answer (score 21):

This works for me

```
msg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
```

and then you can use html in your body

```
msg.Body = "<em>It's great to use HTML in mail!!</em>"
```

Comment: This works for `MailMessage` in [`System.Web.Mail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.bodyformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Doing `IsBodyHtml` is for the one in [`System.Net.Mail`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml(v=vs.110).aspx)