# Replace email string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So i want to replace an normal email for example: `"teste123@test.com"` to 
 "teste123 < b style ='display : none ;' > null < / b >@test.com"`

until now I've got this:

```
  string expression = @"(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@']+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@']+)*)|('.+'))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))";
            Regex rx = new Regex(expression);
            MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(conteudo.PaginaConteudo);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} matches found in:\n   {1}",
                     matches.Count,
                     conteudo.PaginaConteudo);

            string email,
                   replacement = "<h5 style='display:none;'>null</h5>",
                   mailenc,
                   correctString;

            foreach (Match emails in matches)
            {
                email = emails.Value;
                mailenc = "<h5>"+email + replacement+"</h5>";
                correctString = conteudoOriginal.PaginaConteudo.Replace(email, mailenc);
                conteudoOriginal.PaginaConteudo = correctString;

            }
```

Comment: Split on `@` and  add your string or use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx and add your string.

Comment: What is the problem with this code? What is the expected output? Which email you want to replace in the code?

Comment: You should NEVER have html code written as strings in C#.  You're doing "styling of the UI" within code, and that's terrible separation of concern.  Use CSS for that.  You've also code half the code missing, there's a regex you're using there, and we can't see it :(

Comment: Like i sed i want the output to be from "teste123@test.com" to "teste123 < b style ='display : none ;' > null < / b >@test.com"`

Comment: If the Mail Template is more complex, you can still use [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10513059/6560478) of many Template processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
email = emails.Value.Replace("@","<b style='display:none;'>null</b>@");
```

Comment: @dorinmunteanu if it worked then consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Can i have your skype so i can ask some more question about this topic ? @KemalGüler

Comment: Here is my skype id: kemalgulr @dorinmunteanu