# How to use bold text inside Visual Studio String

Tags: javascript, string, visual-studio-2010, escaping

I am trying to edit the content of an email inside our site's backend in visual studio. How do I put bold text? The paragraph is below:

> String body = "PLEASE NOTE: This message contains important and private information, including your User Name and PIN. We suggest that you save this message in a secure place, where others do not have access, for future reference." + "\n\n"

I cannot find a way to type bold text using escape characters \", can I simply type the  tags?

`String body = "<b>PLEASE NOTE:</b>"`

Comment: If the string is going to be interpreted as HTML then wrapping it in <b> tags should work. What have you tried?

Comment: You can just add tags, but you also have to ensure that the email is being sent as an HTML email, not plain text - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628683/how-to-send-html-formated-email and its duplicate